# jquery - making a compound selector

Tags: jquery

I've got several buttons that have the same class but apply to different data (albums), so I added an ID to differentiate between them. Because each album has a unique ID, I don't have to worry about having more than one ID on a page:

```
<button class="addalbum" id="add<?php echo $a->album_id; ?>">Add album</button>

so the IDs would look like: #add121, #add122, etc.
```

**How do I select one of these ids for a jQuery function?** I tried the code below:

```
var a = $(elm).attr('id');

$('.addalbum' + a).click(function() {
//stuff here
});
```

Comment: wrap it in a div with an id and then do `#divwrapper > button `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
$('.addalbum' + a).click(function() {
//stuff here
});
```

to

```
$('#' + a).click(function() {
//stuff here
});
```

Since IDs are unique there's no need to preface it with the class of anything. Also, you need to refer to the id by preceding it with a `#`

Comment: Thanks for this. I've accepted your answer. Just out of curiousity, what element does elm refer to? The jQuery object that is returned, or something else?

Comment: Based on your code, not a thing. Is there more code you have to share?

Answer (score 1):

well it would be #id-name

```
var a = $(elm).attr('id');
$('#'+a).click(function() {
//stuff here
});
```

let me know if its help ;)